# ant does not expand my scala home directory

Tags: scala, ant

Hi I am using ant to build a scala android project.  It seems my ${scala_home} does not expand and I have to hard code the scala location. I obviously dont want to do this.

Any thoughts on what I may be doing incorrectly. It looks like no env variables are expanded in the script. I have tested this with < echo message="${PATH}" / > and ${PATH}

Comment: post your build script and check if the variable is valid or not. If it is not valid, ant will not resolve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment variables are not automatically available to be referenced as properties within an Ant build.

Two options for passing an environment variable to Ant:

- Supply the variable on the Ant command line as a property definition
- Set a [prefix](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) to be used to access environment variables via properties

For the first you might use:

```
$ ant -Dscala_home=$SCALA_HOME
```

Which would make set the `scala_home` property for the build.

For the second you might use:

```
<property environment="env" />
```

to specify the prefix, then you can see the value in this way:

```
<echo message="${env.SCALA_HOME}" />
```

If you somehow have a complex build.xml that relies on an un-prefixed property - `${scala_home}` - then you could copy the value over from the environment using

```
<property environment="env" />
<property name="scala_home" value="${env.scala_home}" />
```

(Note that you may need to adjust case in environment variable names.)

Comment: Thanks - I ran both of these solutions and they work perfectly - will probably go with <property environment="env" />